# Installing nodejs on linux ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

So i have been searching and searching for an answer but I install node using brew install package. It installs node and then when I do node -v or node --version it says node program is not installed yet, when i try to install it again its says the current version of node is currently installed.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't already, follow the install docs from NodeJS' website.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Working on a fresh install Ubuntu 16.04 box.